# How to "wrap" rows in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-wrangling

I currently have a data set that has all information within one single row (or column if I transpose).
The very first items in the data are actually column names:

```
Country | Population | Country Column One | Country Column 2 | USA | 400 million | USA Column 1 | USA Column 2 | Canada | 38 Million | Canada Column 1 | Canada Column 2 | etc..
```

I notice that I can just "wrap" and have everything start at a new row once it reaches a new country. How would I go about that? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: How would you know where the country lies? Is there any specific values that go into these columns? Can you give an example of the true data that you have?

Comment: @onyambu they are simply characters in each column. They are evenly spaced. The specific values other than name of country and population # are percentages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d <- t(matrix(scan(text=string, sep='|', what = "", strip.white = TRUE), 4))

colnames(d) <- d[1,]
data.frame(d[-1,])

  Country  Population Country.Column.One Country.Column.2
1     USA 400 million       USA Column 1     USA Column 2
2  Canada  38 Million    Canada Column 1  Canada Column 2
```

---

```
string <- "Country | Population | Country Column One | Country Column 2 | USA | 400 million | USA Column 1 | USA Column 2 | Canada | 38 Million | Canada Column 1 | Canada Column 2 "
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom approach:

1. We create a tibble separate the rows and pull it as vector
2. with split we create a list
3. then we use bind_rows and do pivoting.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_vec <- as_tibble(string) %>% 
  separate_rows("value", sep = " \\| ") %>%
  pull(value) 

my_list <- split(my_vec, ceiling(seq_along(my_vec) / 4))


bind_rows(my_list) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-`1`) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = `1`, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-name)
```

```
 Country Population  `Country Column One` `Country Column 2`
  <chr>   <chr>       <chr>                <chr>             
1 USA     400 million USA Column 1         "USA Column 2"    
2 Canada  38 Million  Canada Column 1      "Canada Column 2 "
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `read.table` + `gsub`

```
> read.table(text = gsub("(([^|]+\\|){3}[^|]+)\\|", "\\1\n", s),sep = "|",header = TRUE)
   Country    Population Country.Column.One  Country.Column.2
1     USA   400 million       USA Column 1      USA Column 2
2  Canada    38 Million    Canada Column 1   Canada Column 2
```

given

```
s <- "Country | Population | Country Column One | Country Column 2 | USA | 400 million | USA Column 1 | USA Column 2 | Canada | 38 Million | Canada Column 1 | Canada Column 2 "
```